# appengine-mapper library and 1.6.6 appengine-api-labs.jar conflicting

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm trying to use the java appengine mapreduce library (here: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) but it seems to be conflicting with a half implementation of mapreduce in the labs jar of the 1.6.6 appengine SDK.

I simply created a new web application project in eclipse, followed the directions at the link above to add mapper.jar to my project and tested whether I could goto localhost:8888/mapreduce/status. It throws an exception because its trying to use the mapreduce functionality from the labs jar which isn't fully implemented.

How do I force eclipse to use the mapper.jar? I've already listed it first in the the build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to safely remove the `api-labs.jar`. You're seeing a conflict with, for want of a better phrase, something that escaped into the wild prematurely.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Removing the JAR causes eclipse to go bonkers. It wants to "fix" the project by adding it back in.

Comment: O.K. We've looked at this. As an immediate workardound, you can either replace the api-labs.jar with one from the 1.6.5 SDK, or you can manually remove all mapreduce classes from the 1.6.6 jar. Since Eclipse is in the mix, you may need to manually copy the jar from where you've changed it in the SDK into your project's WEB-INF/lib/

Comment: there are multiple appengine-labs-1.6.6.jar files in the SDK, should they all be replaced?

Comment: If you checksum them, you'll see that they're all the same. Replace all of them (keeping their names).